# Inserting data from a temp table into a permanent table

Tags: sql-server, insert, temp-tables

My goal is to find differences between two tables and put the result into a permanent table.

The code is:

```
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #TempTable ([number] nvarchar(255))
(
SELECT [number] FROM [TABLE_X] WHERE [TABLE_X.number] 
EXCEPT
SELECT [number] FROM [TABLE_Y] WHERE [TABLE_Y.number] 
) 
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO #TempTable ([number])'
INSERT INTO [Error_messages]
SELECT 'TABLE_X','Table', number+' is missing from the [TABLE_X], but can be found in [TABLE_Y]' ,GETDATE() FROM #TempTable
DROP TABLE #TempTable
END
```

Although I can see that the first part is successfully ran, but the second part is crashing I got incorrect syntax messages is it because I want to mix dynamic insert with static inserts?

[image]

Comment: `EXECUTE sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO #TempTable ([number])'` is incomplete; where is the rest of the `INSERT` statement? You need a `VALUES` table construct or `SELECT` statement here. Also, why use `sys.sp_executesql` when the statement isn't dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your query has many syntax errors
- It's unclear why you need dynamic SQL, or why you need a temporary table
- You don't describe what the permanent table should look like, I've had a guess
- Based on the message you are trying to store, the `EXCEPT` is the wrong way round

```sql
CREATE TABLE NewTable
    (TableName sysname, ObjectType sysname, Message nvarchar(300), DateChecked datetime);

INSERT NewTable
    (TableName, ObjectType, Message, DateChecked)
SELECT 'TABLE_X','Table', number+' is missing from the [TABLE_X], but can be found in [TABLE_Y]' ,GETDATE()
(
SELECT [number] FROM [TABLE_Y]
EXCEPT
SELECT [number] FROM [TABLE_X]
) t
```

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, Thanks for the reply: 1) Clear 2) That was my fault, I tried to find a quick workaround which was not good. The temporary table was needed, because when I started this thing that was my first idea to solve this kind of problem. 3) You are right, we have a perm table w fields [Object], [Type], [Error], [Extract_Timestamp], but that's not important.
Thanks for the help, I made it too complicated.